# Can I customize the code formatting of Dart code in Atom?

Tags: dart, atom-editor, flutter

I just started to use Atom as editor for Dart and Flutter, so I am new on Atom. I googled around to find a way to customize the code formatting configuration for the `dartlang` plugin that will be executed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> by default.

Comment: The dart plugin for Atom automatically formats your code on every save. Are you asking how to turn that off?

Comment: No, i looking for a way to custumize the code style for the code formatting ... for example braces on new line, indents, line length and so on.

Comment: I guess it uses dart_style which is not configurable except for line length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Dart IDE integrations (including this one) use the formatter included in the SDK. You can find some details of it in the following places:

- [Pub dart_style package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_style)
- [Effective Dart: Style](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/style)

The only configurable part is the line length.

There was some interesting discussion on the merits of such a tool (and how many people use it) on the dart-misc list recently:

- [Do people generally use dartfmt?](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/P56eCKMiP7Q).